# How to extract word or sentence from a preceeding tag?

Tags: php, regex, string, text-extraction

How do I extract a word/quoted sentence through a regex or an efficient alternative as such?:

`tag:videos` will extract **videos**

`tag:"my videos"` will extract **my videos**

`riding ponies tag:ponies` will extract **ponies**

`riding ponies tag:"pony rider"` will extract **pony rider**

`riding ponies tag:` will extract nothing

The ability to support multiple tags would also be great, like:

`travelling the world tag:"aussie guy" country:Australia` extracts **aussie guy** for *tag:* and **Australia** for *country:*.

The intention is to incorporate this into a search input box so users can effectively apply filters with their search terms.

Please let me know how I can do this, thanks!

Comment: What have `you` tried ? Also, it's not easy to code what you want. From your example, the word country can be a tag as well.

Comment: `(tag:)\w+` is what I tried, doesn't work precisely nor has quotation detection. I'm very inexperienced in regex, so I'm clueless.

Also. To clarify, country is considered another tag as well. I just want to make sure it's possible to withdraw both phrases from both separate tags if that means sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all `name:value` or `name:"value"` you can use this [**conditional sub-pattern regex**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php) in `preg_match_all` function call:

```
(\w+):"?\K((?(?<=")[^"]*|\w*))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS6aF6/2)

All the `name` will be available in captured group #1 and `value` part will be in captured group #2.

**RegEx Breakup**

```
(\w+)        # match 1 or more word characters in a group
:            # match literal colon
"?           # match a double quote optionally
\K           # reset the matched data so fat
((?...))     # conditional sub-pattern available in 2nd captured group
?(?<=")      # condition is using look-behind if previous character is "
[^"]*        # TRUE: match 0 or more characters that are not "
|            # or if condition fails
\w*          # FALSE: match 0 or more word characters
```

[PHP Code Demo](http://ideone.com/09vCAW)

To match just the `tag` and it's `value` use this regex:

```
\btag:"?\K((?(?<=")[^"]*|\w*))
```

Comment: This is perfect, the only question is how would I approach receiving grabbing the exact `name` and `value`? (PHP-wise)

Comment: Yep, how do you grab let's say only "country:" and "tag:" and the value with it Thanks

Comment: Check updated answer for a sample PHP code. To answer your question for matching `tag` you can use `\btag:"?\K((?(?<=")[^"]*|\w*))`

Comment: `\btag:"?\K((?(?<=")[^"]*|\w*))` does not seem to extract quoted words like `tag:"testing 123"`

Comment: Another question arises. How do you completely omit/remove "tag:testing" from the search result? Example `searching hello tag:videos` = `searching hello`

Comment: You can use [`\btag:"?\K(?!testing)((?(?<=")[^"]*|\w*))`](https://regex101.com/r/zS6aF6/4)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would accomplish what you are after:

```
/tag:('|")?(.+?)(\1|$)/m
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hN2gO2/1

PHP Usage:

```
preg_match_all('/tag:(\'|")?(.+?)(\1|$)/m', 'tag:videos
tag:"my videos"
riding ponies tag:ponies
riding ponies tag:"pony rider"
riding ponies tag:
travelling the world tag:"aussie guy" country:Australia', $match);
print_r($match[2]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => videos
    [1] => my videos
    [2] => ponies
    [3] => pony rider
    [4] => aussie guy
)
```

If the `tag` is interchangeable to any word make that `\w+`.